# Global variable doesn't work-largestString() which takes an array of strings as input and returns the largest string in this array

Tags: javascript

```
 <p id="longeststring">
</p>
  <script>

  var arr=[];
  var longest=arr[0];

  function largestString(arr)
  {
   for (var i=0;i<arr.length;i++)
       {if(arr[i].length>=longest.length)
          {longest=arr[i]}


       }
   return longest;

  }
  z=["what","am","I","doing","now"]
  document.getElementById("longeststring").innerHTML=largestString(z)
</script>
```

So when var longest=arr[0] is inside the function it works, but when I take it outside, it shows"longest not defined". Why is that? I thought by putting it outside the function, the variable "longest" could update itself.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Look up JavaScript scopes. I am by no means an expert on this, but that search term should bring up the relevent information via Google.

Comment: Thank you. I looked it up and here is my guess: by putting it outside of the function it  becomes a global variable, and overwrites the "longest" inside the function. Do you think it's reasonable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you put the expression `var longest=arr[0];` outside the function, the `arr` refers to the global variable. Its value is set to `[]`, so value of its first item is undefined.

But if you put the expression `var longest=arr[0];` inside the scope, the `arr` refers to the parameter, so it will have the correct value.

Comment: Thank you. Here is another problem: When I put both variables inside, it returns"what" instead of "doing". How do I know which variable or parameter I am referring to? Is there a rule?

Comment: When there are several variables with the same name, it always refers to the most local variable. Did you put the variables just inside the function or inside the for statement?

Comment: Ok let me think it over. I put the variables just inside the function.

Comment: I am not sure why it's returning "what". I tested in my side, but it's not working in that way. By the way, I strongly recommend using let or const instead of var.

Comment: Ok thank you! I haven't learnt let and const so far, but I will look into them. Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

@bran0's answer is correct. I suggest you can write `var longest = ""` instead of `var longest = arr[0]` because `arr`'s length may be zero and `longest` will be undefined in that case.

Comment: That's also useful. Thank you!

Comment: Thank you! There is another question: what would happen if I write the return statement inside the for statement?

Comment: @JiangYuxin, it will be wrong if you do this. Function will return the first item encountered no matter what the length of it.

Comment: I see. Thank you for responding!